# SQL Function to return part of a string and Rename a part of String

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to run a query in SQL to return only part of string against a column.

The string itself contains many characters, but I only want to return the following:

name="ABCD"

Sample String which is just a row of garbled XML code.

```
<Help><field id="123" type="0" name="CTRLID" formatstring=""><oldValue> <![CD[1234]]></oldValue><newValue><![CD[12345]></newValue></field><field id="123456" type="5" name="SearchMe" formatstring <setChoice>123456789</setChoice></field></Help>
```

The above is just a string in a row.

I want `name="CTRLID"` to return and `name="SearchMe"` to return only. Lastly, I want to change `name` to `Field`. The column that I am searching against is called MD.

What function can be used to perform these actions and what do I need to follow?

Example: SUBSTRING([MD],44,600)

Comment: can there be more than one `name="FindMe"` in the column?

Comment: are you passing the complete XML or just a part of the full XML as a sting? Also if you could just post the string/XML rather than an image that would be better.

Comment: vkp - yes there is more than name="find me"  I will post the full string to view.

Comment: Kamran - i added the XML.

Comment: it could be more.  I would to identify all the instances and have them separated with a comma.

Comment: I think the edits to your original question have vandalized your question.

Comment: @jeff I don't think SQL Server has an out of the box function you can use but in my answer I have tried to show how this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Jeff so you have the XML as:

```
<Help>
    <field id="123" type="0" name="CTRLID" formatstring="">
        <oldValue>
             <![CD[1234]]>
        </oldValue>
        <newValue>
             <![CD[12345]>
        </newValue>
    </field>
    <field id="123456" type="5" name="SearchMe" formatstring="">
        <setChoice>123456789</setChoice>
    </field>
</Help>
```

However sql server doesn't seem to like `<![CD[1234]]>` and prefers `<![CDATA[1234]]>`

You can see in my solution I have changed the data so that the CDATA is written as `<![CDATA[1234]]>`

But essentially you need to do something like the following:

ASSUMPTION:

the data within the column is of XML datatype

QUERY:

```
DECLARE @XML XML = '<Help>
    <field id="123" type="0" name="CTRLID" formatstring="">
        <oldValue>
             <![CDATA[1234]]> 
        </oldValue>
        <newValue>
             <![CDATA[12345]]> 
        </newValue>
    </field>
    <field id="123456" type="5" name="SearchMe" formatstring="">
        <setChoice>123456789</setChoice>
    </field>
</Help>';

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEMP') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TEMP;

SELECT T.c.query
      ('.') AS Field
INTO #TEMP
FROM   @XML.nodes
    ('/Help/field') T(c);

SELECT Field.value('(/field/@name)[1]', 'varchar(100)') as [Field]
FROM   #TEMP;
```

RESULT:

[image]

RESOURCES USED:

[nodes() Method (xml Data Type)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms188282.aspx)

Hope it helps

RESPOND TO COMMENT:

```
DECLARE @STRING VARCHAR(MAX) = '<Help>
    <field id="123" type="0" name="CTRLID" formatstring="">
        <oldValue>
             <![CD[1234]]> 
        </oldValue>
        <newValue>
             <![CD[12345]]> 
        </newValue>
    </field>
    <field id="123456" type="5" name="SearchMe" formatstring="">
        <setChoice>123456789</setChoice>
    </field>
</Help>';

DECLARE @XML XML;

SELECT @XML=CAST( REPLACE (@STRING,'<![CD[','<![CDATA[') AS XML)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEMP') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TEMP;

SELECT T.c.query
      ('.') AS name
INTO #TEMP
FROM   @XML.nodes
    ('/Help/field') T(c);

SELECT name.value('(/field/@name)[1]', 'varchar(100)') as [name]
FROM   #TEMP
FOR XML RAW;
```

[image]

OR YOU CAN DO THIS:

```
DECLARE @STRING VARCHAR(MAX) = '<Help>
    <field id="123" type="0" name="CTRLID" formatstring="">
        <oldValue>
             <![CD[1234]]> 
        </oldValue>
        <newValue>
             <![CD[12345]]> 
        </newValue>
    </field>
    <field id="123456" type="5" name="SearchMe" formatstring="">
        <setChoice>123456789</setChoice>
    </field>
</Help>';

DECLARE @XML XML;

SELECT @XML=CAST( REPLACE (@STRING,'<![CD[','<![CDATA[') AS XML)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEMP') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TEMP;

SELECT T.c.query
      ('.') AS Field
INTO #TEMP
FROM   @XML.nodes
    ('/Help/field') T(c);

SELECT 'name="'+Field.value('(/field/@name)[1]', 'varchar(100)')+'"' as [Field]
FROM   #TEMP;
```

[image]

Comment: Kamran: the XML itself is a string in a row, I just want to return values that look like name="something" from the row.  If there are 2 instances of name="something", i want to return name="something", name ="something for that row as a string. (row format)

Comment: so do you mean like so: <row name="CTRLID" />
<row name="SearchMe" /> If that's the case then check out the edit to my solution

Comment: Yep, from the row itself which is xml coding, i just want to return as a table per row name="sample"

Comment: @Jeff sorry forgot to post the edit to my answer. have a look at it now.

Comment: Kamran: Is there a way to add a wildcard to return other instances of name="sample".  Example: name="%"

Comment: @Jeff not quite sure what you are asking here?

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE YourTable SET YourColumn=REPLACE(YourColumn, 'name="FindMe"', 'Field="FindMe"') WHERE SomeCondition
```

Assuming YourColumn is varchar or nvarchar

Comment: Thank you CB, I am trying to however, not update the table, rather return back the results truncated with certain vales.